# Flow nesting limitations - workaround needed if possible

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I have a 4 approver workflow that I am setting up within Microsoft Flow.  The limitation and requirement set by the End Users is that they don't all want to keep receiving emails for every item before it has been screened. So, the screening process that has to be followed is: Approver 1, Approver 2, 3 etc.

The logic flow is as follows. When Item is created, Start Approval Process one > If approved > Start Approval 2 if approved Start Approval 3, etc.

When fully approved advise user to fill in the rest of the list with post-approval details and select "Complete" option. This then takes the attached document and places it within an approval archive.

I have managed to complete this with TWO approvers. But when we go on to the third cycle, we start running in to the nesting problems.

The only way I have found around this is that I have to place all initial 3 approvers in the first approval, and last approver in the second approval cycle.

I was wondering if there were any alternatives any one else has that would not run in to these nesting issues?

Thank you
[image: Start of Flow]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What nesting problems you are facing exactly? Is it not running if you have used more than two approvals?

Comment: Yes, when I start the third stage I run in to the specific error:  The power flow's logic app flow template was invalid. The template actions 'Get_attachments_2, Apply_to_each_15, Send_an_email_(V2)_14' are nested at level '9' which exceeds the maximum nesting limit of '8'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly, if you can simply have multiple approvers in one approver, using the option to send the approvals out one at a time, that's the best option. But, to avoid nesting, instead of putting approval 2 in the condition following approval 1, put a terminate in the condition, which means that the next approval will run if the flow wasn't terminated.

So:

1. approval 1 action
2. If approval 1 was not approved, then terminate
3. approval 2 action

The above sequence can be repeated with no additional nesting levels.

Comment: That's understood, but it would still limit you with respect to when you get to approval 3. Here, the full sequence must be completed for the item to be approved. Approval 1-4 must all be completed, but eventually you will always get in to the problem of nesting. If only there was an approval node that did sequential approvals, as opposed to emailing all approvers at once.

Comment: Not sure I understand your concern. the above could be repeated as needed, as there is no nesting involved at all. And, the only way it proceeds is when prior approvals were approved.

Comment: OK, I will try this terminate route. I don't think I read the question answer properly right off the bat. Thank you. I will feedback shortly.

Comment: Mike2500 is right. The answer is to use Terminate if the condition is not met which will kill the Flow. The logical flow is as follows: When Item Created > Start Appoval > If Approved > Send Email (consequently this will allow you to go in to Approval 2) > If Rejected > Terminate.     Seems a little obvious now thinking about it. It means you don't need to keep nesting deeper and deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, this would not cause any nesting problems. Here is my template for you:
[image]

Comment: The nesting problem occurs because I am using Dynamic responses in my feedback to the creator of the  item. The dynamic content picks up the comments from the approver, there for a Nest is created. Im not sure @Mike2500 how the Terminate Node would remove this factor. I just tried to encompass it within the Flow, to no avail.

Comment: Could you please add some screenshots for your flow?

Comment: In your flow, you should use "Outcome" instead of "Responses" as in my template. And i think you don't have to use apply to each action.

Comment: Responses doesn't produce their own nest. The item is being nested because within the email the Approvers responses are being picked up.